# Transparent icons for Visual Studio Addin

Tags: visual-studio-2010, icons, add-in, visual-studio-addins

I'm working with this tutorial:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228771.aspx
But it says, images MUST be 16x16, bmp.
I was wondering, is it possible to use **transparent** icons, and if how?
Also, is it possible that VS2010 (wpf and all) still doesn't support **256x256** png icons?

Comment: You could try also a workaround - PNG renamed to BMP - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9374200/804385

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 32bit bitmaps. See the following Carlos Quintero's blog post for more information [Solved: transparent bitmaps in add-in commands of VS 2010 (Beta 1)](http://msmvps.com/blogs/carlosq/archive/2009/06/25/solved-transparent-bitmaps-in-add-in-commands-of-vs-2010-beta-1.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out when I get the chance