# how can i add a new icon to a Visual Studio 2010 extension?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx, vsix

i'm developing a Visual Studio 2010 extension, i already have a toolbar inside my window. on that toolbar i have a button that i want to give an icon - my own icon!
I've read [this article](http://abhijitjana.net/2011/05/02/customizing-visual-studio-extension-icon-in-visual-studio-2010/) and it is great but... it explains how to **replace** the icons.

i want to **add** an additional icon.

how do i achieve that?

Comment: Depends on how you're making your extension.  Do you have a .vsct file in your project that contains the definition of your buttons?

Comment: yes i do have that! i think I've found an answer but would like to hear yours so i can learn and see if i'm doing right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, add the bitmap and set its build action to **Resource**

[image]

Remember, shocking pink = transparent (damn you, old school!)

[image]

Then, in your `vsct` file, add the image to the bitmaps section

```
<Bitmaps>
    <Bitmap guid="AddSampleData.bmpGuid"
            href="..\Button Bitmaps\AddSampleData.bmp"
            usedList="AddSampleData.bmpId" />
    <Bitmap guid="ApplySampleData.bmpGuid"
            href="..\Button Bitmaps\ApplySampleData.bmp"
            usedList="ApplySampleData.bmpId" />
</Bitmaps>
```

and assign it a guid in the symbols node

```
<Symbols>
    <!-- snip -->
    <GuidSymbol name="AddSampleData.bmpGuid"
                value="{dcae7c84-8e91-4f8a-907b-95ccb0f52e6e}">
        <IDSymbol name="AddSampleData.bmpId"
                    value="1" />
    </GuidSymbol>
    <GuidSymbol name="ApplySampleData.bmpGuid"
                value="{9f555245-2430-4e6f-992b-b49ce87a31a2}">
        <IDSymbol name="ApplySampleData.bmpId"
                    value="1" />
    </GuidSymbol>
</Symbols>
```

and apply it to a button

```
<Buttons>
<!-- snip -->
    <Button guid="guidEditorExtensionCommandSet"
            id="setDesignTimeDataOnPage"
            priority="0x0100">
        <Icon guid="ApplySampleData.bmpGuid"
                id="ApplySampleData.bmpId" />
        <Strings>
                    <!-- snip -->
        </Strings>
    </Button>
</Buttons>
```

Of course, its always easier to use the available tools, including the excellent [VSPackage Builder extension.](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e9f40a57-3c9a-4d61-b3ec-1640c59549b3)

[image]

Comment: great, tnx, that exactly what i did! BUT... with a .png not .bmp - it makes life easier when it come to transparency. the only difference is that you don't need the usedList inside the Bitmap tag.

Answer (score 6):

A workaround for this is to **create a PNG and rename the extension as *.bmp**. VS will accept it as an icon image and it will also have transparency (from Visual Studio Extensibility > [Toolbox Icons -- Is transparency supported?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsx/thread/20e74a0c-c1ca-4a73-b6c0-5cef00ae4e94))

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this trick Dmitry. This is going to make my life SO much easier! :-)