# How do I change icon on a Visual Studio Integration Package (VSPackage)?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vspackage

So I have a standard Visual Studio Integration Package that I created using the VS2010 Visual Studio Integration Wizard that pretty much has the following code and I am trying to figure out how to change the icon in the Tools menu for my project:

```
<PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly:=True), _
InstalledProductRegistration("#110", "#112", "1.0", IconResourceID:=400), _
ProvideMenuResource("Menus.ctmenu", 1), _
Guid(GuidList.guidDALDesigner_VSPackPkgString)> _
Public NotInheritable Class DALDesigner_VSPackPackage
    Inherits Package
...
```

I keep seeing the icon for "1" next to my menu item. How do I change the icon to one that I want?

Comment: @Omribitan - of course and FYI, this is VSPackage, not a Visual Studio AddIn

Comment: hmmm ... what about the 'change icon' button in page 2 of the wizard? taken from : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc138589(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Omribitan - yeah, I was thinking the same but I don't know how to get the wizard back since I already have the project :-) It must be in the XML file or code somewhere... Just don't know where...

Comment: Try creating a new VSPackage project, change the icon in the wizard, then compare the generated code/xml. Sorry I'm just tossing ideas without posting code or example. I've never worked with VSPackage just tryin' to help :)

Comment: @Omribitan - appreciate it. I'll try.

Comment: didn't work, that was the image for the icon of the application

Answer (score 0):

That's set in the .vsct file. See for example [how can i add a new icon to a Visual Studio 2010 extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092595/how-can-i-add-a-new-icon-to-a-visual-studio-2010-extension)

I think VS does some caching behind the scenes though and your modified icons might not get picked up immediately.
The experimental instance didn't have that "problem" in my tests.